# Only getting the first result with a has many relationship

Tags: php, laravel

This is my migration:

```
Schema::create('seasons', function (Blueprint $table) {
     $table->bigIncrements('id');
     $table->bigInteger('show_id')->unsigned();
     $table->bigInteger('season');
     $table->timestamps();
});

Schema::table('seasons', function(Blueprint $table) {
    $table->foreign('show_id')->references('id')->on('shows');
});
```

Which outputs this for example

```
# id, show_id, season, created_at, updated_at
'1', '1', '1', '2019-04-12 21:04:40', '2019-04-12 21:04:40'
'2', '1', '2', '2019-04-12 21:04:40', '2019-04-12 21:04:40'
'3', '1', '3', '2019-04-12 21:04:40', '2019-04-12 21:04:40'
'4', '1', '4', '2019-04-12 21:04:40', '2019-04-12 21:04:40'
'5', '1', '5', '2019-04-12 21:04:40', '2019-04-12 21:04:40'
'6', '1', '6', '2019-04-12 21:04:40', '2019-04-12 21:04:40'
'7', '1', '7', '2019-04-12 21:04:40', '2019-04-12 21:04:40'
'8', '1', '8', '2019-04-12 21:04:40', '2019-04-12 21:04:40'
'9', '1', '9', '2019-04-12 21:04:40', '2019-04-12 21:04:40'
'10', '1', '10', '2019-04-12 21:04:40', '2019-04-12 21:04:40'
```

Then in the `Show` model I have this

```
public function seasons()
{
    return $this->hasMany('App\Season', 'season');
}
```

And now in my blade file when I'm trying to echo all of the season numbers, when showing a specific show.

```
@foreach($show->seasons as $season)
    {{ $season->season }}
@endforeach
```

This only shows me `1`. When I dd the variable only the first seasons is in it.

How can this happen, because I defined that a show has multiple seasons. If someone could point me in the right direction, I'd greatly appreciate it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this on your Show model:

```
public function seasons()
{
    return $this->hasMany('App\Season');
}
```

Comment: The second argument on the hasMany is the foreign key, show_id in this case, but given that you followed Laravel convention and named it with the table name in singular and _id, you can omit that second argument.